# Pintu and Friends - CodeChef

Tags: c

Question Link : https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHPINTU

My code keeps showing wrong answer. I tested it for a few examples on my local compiler and it works fine there.

Answer Link : https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/30712784

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int t, m, n, i, j, k, min;
scanf("%d", &t);
int ans[t];
for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int p[n], f[n];
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &f[j]);
    }
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &p[j]);
    }
    for(j=1; j<=m; j++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(k=0; k<n; k++)
        {
            if(f[k]==j)
                count+=p[k];
        }
        if(j==0)
            min=count;
        if(min>count && count!=0)
            min=count;
    }
    ans[i]=min;
}
for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", ans[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `if(j==0) min=count;` but`j` is never `0` in that loop. Better to initialise `min` at the start of each test case.

Answer (score 1):

Since your loop start from `for(j=1; j<=m; j++)`  `j=1` then this `if(j==0)` will never be true ,change it to:

```
    for(j=1; j<=m; j++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(k=0; k<n; k++)
        {
            if(f[k]==j)
                count+=p[k];
        }
        if(j==1)
            min=count;
        if(min>count && count!=0)
            min=count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted code does not cleanly compile. Amongst other problems, this code:

```
if(j==0) 
    min=count; 
if(min>count && count!=0)
```

can result in the variable `min` not being initialized before its' contents being accessed in the if() statement. The result is undefined behavior.

Note: Windows, in debug mode, initializes the stack to all 0x00, however, that does not happen in the 'real world'

{EDIT}

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. (seems) to perform the desired functionality
3. checks for I/O errors, although most online places don't care

caveat: not tested at the online site

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_BASKETS 50

int main( void )
{
    int testcases;  
    if( scanf("%d", &testcases) != 1 ) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

    for( int i=0; i<testcases; i++)
    {
        int numBaskets;
        int fruitTypes;

        if( scanf("%d %d", &numBaskets, &fruitTypes) != 2) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

        struct basket
        {
            int fruitType;
            int price;
        };  

        struct basket baskets[ MAX_BASKETS ];
        for( int j=0; j<MAX_BASKETS; j++ )
        {
            baskets[j].fruitType = -1;
            baskets[j].price = -1;
        }

        // get type fruit for each basket
        for( int j=0; j<numBaskets; j++)
        {
            if( scanf("%d", &baskets[j].fruitType) != 1) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        for( int j=0; j<numBaskets; j++)
        {

            if( scanf("%d", &baskets[j].price) != 1 ) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        int sum[ MAX_BASKETS ];
        for( int j = 0; j < MAX_BASKETS; j++ )
        {
            sum[j] = -1;
        }

        for( int j=0; j<numBaskets; j++)
        {
            if( baskets[j].price != -1 )
            {
                sum[ baskets[j].fruitType ] += baskets[j].price;
            }
        }

        int min = INT_MAX;

        for( int j=0; j<MAX_BASKETS; j++ )
        {
            if( sum[j] < min && sum[j] > 0)
            {
                min = sum[j];
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", min);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to coding. I don't understood most of what you have said, can you please explain or provide any useful links?

Comment: regarding: *The posted code does not cleanly compile*  when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: when running code on Windows, if it is in debug mode, then the stack is initialized to all 0x00.  When in production mode, the stack contains what ever trash is in memory at the location of the stack.

Comment: regarding: `if(j==0) 
    min=count; 
if(min>count && count!=0)` Since `j` is never 0, the variable `min` never gets set to `count` so the variable `min` is not initialized.  This logic problem needs to be corrected